# How does cover / line of sight work in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

Cover/line-of-sight appears to work slightly differently in XCOM 2.  For example, take this situation:

[image: Unit can't attack!]

In XCOM:EU, my unit would be able to attack the enemy in this situation *(see for example [this explanation of how LOS works in XCOM:EU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8GNF.gif), under side-stepping)*.

However, as you can see, she can't attack him.  Why?  How has cover/LOS changed in XCOM 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one (other than Firaxis) can know for sure, here's my interpretation of your picture:

The soldier you're trying to target isn't standing in the open door, but next to it. He's standing in the same line as your soldier, and the full-cover-box you can see behind the doorway.

I think it's that specific box that is blocking your LOS. Even if we consider that your soldier sidesteps (so let's assume she's standing one tile to her left); it's possible that the slight elevation of the train cart combined with the angle of the box (relative to how your unit would see the enemy soldier) leads the game to decide it's not in LOS.

That being said, this is just a guess. I remember being in similar situation and seeing my target. The only thing different here is that box, which is why I'm thinking that's the reason.

**Edit**
For those who argue that the enemy (model) is in sight of the soldier, therefore it should be targetable, keep in mind that the game calculates based on the *tile* a unit is on, not the actual visibility of their character model.

I find that units in cover really cling to the cover, or try to pop out their heads, and it throws off your vision on where the tile is located. If you look at OP's picture, you'll see how much difference there is between the enemy's body and the actual center of the tile they're standing on.

Comment: I've since learned _(from a PointPoint included with the XCOM 2 SDK)_ that in XCOM:EU, targeting **was** actually based on the actual visibility of the character models, but they reworked that in XCOM 2 to decouple the logic from the view code.  So this change just seems to be a bug _(I believe this is also why my units keep getting shot through the damn floor now)_

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely an answer, but a bit too big for a comment. If you're looking to achieve a certain shot from a position, you can check the shot **before** you even make the move by using the line of sight indicator.

> Line of Sight Indicator: I'd heard of this, but hadn't had anybody explain where it was. It's a tiny cross-hair next to an enemy's health bar. If that's there, then your unit will be able to fire on that enemy from your cursor's current position. /u/Infernal_Dalek

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/44b7pf/xcom_2_tips_megathread/

Comment: Wow. Where was that in the tutorial? Leaving out some vital information.

Comment: It's also not always 100% reliable, though only in the opposite direction - you will sometimes find that even if the indicator didn't show, you will still have LoS once you're done moving. This is very irritating if, for instance, you're trying to use it in order to get a heavily injured soldier to somewhere they won't be shot at...